# SNMP Agent: Could mib2c generate code for InetAddress or String type (ie something not an integer type)

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmpd

I was able to transform 95% of a dedicated MIB to C code and make it run in a sub-agent like described in the last part of this [Net-SNMP tutorial](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Writing_a_Subagent)

For this I naturally use the *mib2c.mfd.conf* (I just read that *mfd* stands for Mib For Dummies ... all is said ...)

```
mib2c -I -c mib2c.mfd.conf my_mib_node
```

It generated a long .c file with almost all the oids like the one below.

*Almost no lines were generated for the VideoInetAddr OID*

```c
//ABSTRACT OF SOURCE FILE GENERATED BY MIB2C
//...

long    VideoFormat = 0;  /* XXX: set default value */
// <<<=== NOTHING GENERATED HERE FOR VideoInetAddr OF TYPE INETADDRESS
// WHEREAS OTHER INTEGERS ARE NORMALLY PRESENT
long    VideoInetPort = 0;  /* XXX: set default value */
//...

void init_my_mib_node(void)
{
 //...

    const oid VideoFormat_oid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,a,b,c,d,e };
    static netsnmp_watcher_info VideoFormat_winfo;
    // <<<=== NO OID GENERATED for VideoInetAddr OF TYPE INETADDRESS
    // WHEREAS OTHER OIDs ARE NORMALLY GENERATED
    static netsnmp_watcher_info VideoInetAddr_winfo; //We have the winfo after all
    const oid VideoInetPort_oid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,a,b,c,d,g };
    static netsnmp_watcher_info VideoInetPort_winfo;

    DEBUGMSGTL(("my_mib_node",
    "Initializing VideoFormat scalar integer.  Default value = %d\n",
                VideoFormat));

    reg = netsnmp_create_handler_registration(
         "VideoFormat", NULL,
          VideoFormat_oid, OID_LENGTH(VideoFormat_oid),
          HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE);

    netsnmp_init_watcher_info(&VideoFormat_winfo, &VideoFormat, 
    sizeof(long),ASN_INTEGER, WATCHER_FIXED_SIZE);

   if (netsnmp_register_watched_scalar( reg, &VideoFormat_winfo ) < 0 ) {
    snmp_log( LOG_ERR, "Failed to register watched VideoFormat" );
   //...
}
```

This worked fine and needed 5 minutes (no code to write, just call the init() function), I was able to GET and SET all ... integers  ...

*Some oids are of Type InetAddress were not generated, neither were strings*

**Question**

- Is there a mib conf file able to generate code for every type

I tried the *mib2c.old-api.conf* which generates code also for the non-integer oids but I find it not as convenient. There is more boilerplate code to write.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, mib2c **could** generate code for IP addresses. *I cannot say that mfd does this, but, definitely, some mib2c.iterate.conf (for tables) does this.*

The type of IP in SNMP is **ASN_IPADDRESS** represented by **unint32_t** in C.
Also,You need to make sure that in MIB-file for object, which represents IP, you have "**SYNTAX  IpAddress**".

Have a look:
[at the MIB file with IP object](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.2.1.6.13.1.2.html) and [implementation in C](https://github.com/haad/net-snmp/blob/master/agent/mibgroup/mibII/tcpTable.c)

Comment: The IP definition  I have in my MIB is  `SYNTAX      InetAddress`.  I do not know exactly where this is defined. In Net-SNMP directory there is the _mibs_ directory where I found _INET-ADDRESS_MIB.txt_. There you have `InetAddress ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION ... SYNTAX       OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..255))`. That's why in my own answer to my question I use `ASN_OCTET_STR`. I found `ASN_OCTET_STR` in _Net-SNMP/include/net-snmp/library/asn1.h_ and value is 0x04. `ASN_IPADDRESS` is in _Net-SNMP/include/net-snmp/library/libsnmp.h_ or _snmp_impl.h_ and value is 0x40.

Comment: The MIB file come from a third-party and I think I have no other choice than coping with it. Are there ''good" SNMP IP adress types and "bad" ones ? Maybe with ASN_IPADDRESS mib2c would have generated dedicated code ?

Comment: "Some oids are of Type InetAddress were not generated, neither were strings" I didn't paid enough attention to this before.
In order for mib2c generate the best code possible your MiB file suppose to define every custom type used in it, or import them from the MiB which does. 

Here some information and examples for the code you need to add to the MIB (you can create just temporary version of it just for generating template code) https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/73515-import-mib-file:-missing-import-module:-rfc-1212

Comment: My MIB file already had `IMPORTS ...InetPortNumber, InetAddress     FROM INET-ADDRESS-MIB` and I check again  with `export MIBS=all`. The result is the same. I think that mfd is not the right file for my present needs as it first ask you to check between _1) ucd-snmp style code_ which has all but incomplete and _2) Net-SNMP style code_. After choosing 2 you choose _1)  you're writing code for some generic scalars_ (which is the same as ucd-snmp style) or _2)  magically "tie" integer variables to integer scalars_. Again choosing 2 explicitely gives you _integer_  only

Comment: yeah, i know :) Right now I'm developing some SNMP agent and at the begging, I was also using mfd. But at the end of day MibsForDummies wasn't so "For dummies". And we started to use for tables mib2c.iterate.conf and for scalars mib2c.scalar.conf in most cases.

Comment: try to run *mib2c -c mib2c.scalar.conf VideoInetAddr* just to see if it will give any result ( if this element is a part of a table then mib2c.iterate.conf)

Comment: _mib2c -c mib2c.scalar.conf VideoInetAddr_ generates more or less an empty shell. The oid[] array is not generated. No _netsnmp_init_watcher_info(...)_ or useful stuff like this...

Answer (score 0):

**Piece of answer but I am very far from comprehension and so side problems persist**

Very pragmatically I managed to add by hand

```c
//I put here ONLY what I added, see question above to complete code
#define STR_LENGTH_IPV4 sizeof("xxx.yyy.zzz.www")
char   VideoInetAddr[STR_LENGTH_IPV4] = "192.168.2.3";
//...
const oid VideoInetAddr_oid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,a,b,c,d,f };

reg = netsnmp_create_handler_registration(
         "VideoInetAddr", NULL,
          VideoInetAddr_oid, OID_LENGTH(VideoInetAddr_oid),
          HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE);

netsnmp_init_watcher_info(&VideoInetAddr_winfo, &VideoInetAddr, sizeof(VideoInetAddr),
              ASN_OCTET_STR,  WATCHER_MAX_SIZE );

if (netsnmp_register_watched_scalar( reg, &VideoInetAddr_winfo ) < 0 ) {
    snmp_log( LOG_ERR, "Failed to register watched VideoInetAddr" );
}
```

It still need to understand exactly the option like WATCHER_MAX_SIZE (is-it the good one ?)